Click a button to go to a URL in a Jupyter notebook
I want to be able to open http://example.com when clicking on an ipywidgets.Button (ideally in the same tab).
I tried
def on_click(btn):
  display(Javascript('window.open("http://example.com");'))

and
def on_click(btn):
  display(Javascript('window.location.href = "http://example.com";'))

as on_click callbacks, but nothing happens when I click the button.

Does this help? https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/widget-button-to-open-url/11634

Fantastic, thank you!


This is because the notebook does not know where to display the
Javascript object, so instead it logs it in the console to let you
know that something is amiss. One solution would be to point your
display to a specific Output:
display, Javascript

out = widgets.Output()


def window_open_button(url):
    with out:
        display(Javascript(f'window.open("{url.tooltip}");'))


ss = widgets.Button(description="hello",
tooltip='https://www.google.com') ss.on_click(window_open_button)

with out:
    display(ss) out 


Source: Michał Krassowski at the Jupyter Community Discourse Forum

Note that depending on what flavor of Jupyter you are using to develop in, you won't see the Log Console. This is a JupyterLab feature at this time. At present, JupyterLab is best for developing with ipywidgets. Having to specify how to handle the output from actions inside widgets is a general requirement now in ipywidgets, not limited to this use case or button use. TIP: there's a lot of old code out there that doesn't cover the more modern use of ipywidgets and leaves out this handling.
